# KLDIV Kullback-Leibler or Jensen-Shannon divergence between two distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance, kullback-leibler

let consider following probability distributions

```
X   P                Q           Kullback                      Kullback_divergence
1   0.526810511     0.6557  -0.166341349                        11.97922287
2   0.213080233     0.0357  0.54919316      
3   0.02600177     0.8491   -0.130769473        
4   0.088595233     0.934   -0.301057372        
5   0.546739097    0.6787   -0.170539661        
6   0.28479873     0.7577   -0.40204582     
7   0.082491531     0.7431  -0.261600315        
8   0.106326487   0.3922    -0.200222185        
9   0.92608417    0.6555    0.461696987     
10  0.866939299   0.1712    2.028853203     
11  0.122989593     0.706   -0.310072991        
12  0.782494583   0.0318    3.615893457     
13  0.030182806     0.2769  -0.09651152     
14  0.580645161   0.0462    2.120337307     
15  0.632129887     0.0971  1.708443428     
16  0.118564409     0.8235  -0.331517665        
17  0.98791467     0.6948   0.501651889     
18  0.139591662     0.3171  -0.165238155        
19  0.668691061   0.9502    -0.338953731        
20  0.839289529   0.0344    3.868023675
```

i would like to know what this number shows  us?does this express information  about second distribution?or what is distance between two distribution,as i know if it far from $1$,then it means that they are really different,but which is good and real?please i need your advice's

Comment: I do not see any probability distributions here. It would appear that "X" is a column indexing 20 distinct outcomes and that "P" and "Q" are supposed to be probabilities, *but they cannot be,* since they each sum to far more than $1$.

Comment: yes maybe,i did not pay attention about this,i just  generate  ranadom numbers

Comment: When the example has nothing to do with the question it makes things very confusing.

Comment: anyway  forget about if sum exceed $1$,i  am interested about method itself,then can be  numbers even more then 10000 in value :D

Comment: for example what 11.97  will shows us?

Comment: Nothing: it has to be treated as nonsensical because it was derived from nonsensical input.

Comment: let forget @whuber about nonsensical input,just imagine that it is sensical input,i understood what is it nonsense,but suppose it is,i dont not need philosophy there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Kullback-Leibler is a "directed divergence measure", the meaning depends on which direction was computed. Can you provide the formula you used? If you computed p(x) ln(p(x)/q(x), then this measure tells you the following: (1) the information lost when Q is used to approximate P, or (2) the amount if information obtained per observation of X that allows one to discriminate between P and Q. The first interpretation is often used for coding or compression and indicates how well Q approximates P. The second interpretation is used in hypothesis testing to indicate how easily the Q distribution can be declared to be different from the P distribution.

Comment: yes $p(x)*ln(p(x)/q(x)$

Comment: how if i got some  value $k$,then what does it mean?